# Difference between CUBE and WITH CUBE

Tags: sql, t-sql, cube, rolap

I found in MSSQL exists both

```
SELECT <list of columns>, sum(measure) as measure    
FROM fact-table
GROUP BY <list of columns> WITH CUBE
```

and

```
SELECT <list of columns>, sum(measure) as measure    
FROM fact-table
GROUP BY CUBE (<list of columns>)
```

I was wandering what is the difference, because using them, I get same results with both syntaxes.

Also I remember that, at least for version 2008, WITH CUBE was supported by express edition and ROLLUP(), CUBE() and GROUPING SETS() were a feature of 'Enterprise editions'

Comment: I don't think there is a difference.  To be honest, I usually use `grouping sets` so the summary dimensions are explicit.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database
>   ISO-Compliant Syntax
>
> ```
> GROUP BY {
>       column-expression  
>     | ROLLUP ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
>     | CUBE ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
>     | GROUPING SETS ( <grouping_set> [ ,...n ]  )  
>     | () --calculates the grand total 
> } [ ,...n ]
> ```

> For backward compatibility only.
>   Non-ISO-Compliant Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database
>
> ```
> GROUP BY 
>       [ ALL ] column-expression [ ,...n ] 
>     | column-expression [ ,...n ] [ WITH { CUBE | ROLLUP } ]
> ```

and:

> ```
> Feature   SQL Server             SQL Server                SQL Server 2008 or later
>           Integration Services   compatibility level 100   with compatibility level 90
>                                  or higher
>
> CUBE      Not supported          Supported                 Not supported
>
> WITH CUBE Supported              Supported                 Supported
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **WITH** keyword is optional in all contexts except starting a CTE declaration, in this case - both do the exact same thing